# How to create a method for multiple data types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, indexof

I have written a method called `contains` which checks a string to see if it has a specified string in inside it (see below for code).

Since this code works for strings, I would like to also have it work on arrays, but I cannot find a way to do that (if I create another method of the same name but with `Array` instead of `String` it raises a TypeError).

How would I do this?

Code:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(subst) {
    var string = this;
    if (string.indexOf(subst) == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

BTW: I am writing this, rather than using the built in `indexOf`, method just to improve the readability of my code.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(subst) {
    var array = this;
    if (array.indexOf(subst) == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I am calling it using:

```
var arr = ['1','2','3','4'];
console.log(arr.contains('1'));
```

Which raises the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: arr.contains is not a function`

Comment: There already is such a method, called `includes`.

Comment: Show the code that causes a type error, because that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also there are two "code smells" in that method: first, mixing `return` with `if ... else`, and second, using an `if` to pick between returning `true` or `false`. The body of the code could be just `return this.indexOf(subst) !== -1;`.

Comment: What about not using 'this' and not extending the default prototypes? Just: `function( obj, value ) { return obj.indexOf( value ) !== -1; }` works for any entity that has an indexOf() method.

Comment: Your error is probably coming from putting an enumerable property on `Array.prototype` and then using an non-idiomatic JS way of iterating an Array by using `for-in` instead of `for` or something else that constrains the iteration to numeric indices. Using `for-in` on Arrays just sucks in JS for multiple reasons.

Comment: When I run the code that causes an error for you, it works fine.

Comment: On Node.js v7.7.1 your code runs just fine.

Comment: Where do you call `console.log(...)` after altering the prototype or before?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I call it after altering the prototype